# Switching tab panes on selection option change

Tags: jquery, html, menu, tabs, nav

I have two different menus that display search menus to users, one is displayed on medium to large displays, one is mobile only.

For the large and medium display one, there are tabs that a user can use to switch between the different resources they want to search through

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs search-nav-tabs hidden-sm-down">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#articlesplus" data-toggle="tab">ArticlesPlus</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#alice" data-toggle="tab">ALICE Catalog</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#databases" data-toggle="tab">Databases</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#reserves" data-toggle="tab">Course Reserves</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#guides" data-toggle="tab">Subject & Course Guides</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#cdm" data-toggle="tab">Digital Archives</a></li>
</ul>
```

The mobile menu is the one I am having trouble with. For this one a select menu is being utilized as follows:

```
<!-- The order/values of the select must match the index of the corresponding tab -->
<form class="search-nav hidden-md-up">
  <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
    <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Search In:</label>
    <div class="col-8 text-right">
      <select id="search-nav-select" class="form-control">
        <option value='0' data-toggle="#articlesplus">ArticlesPlus</option>
        <option value='1' data-toggle="#alice">ALICE Catalog</option>
        <option value='2' data-toggle="#databases">Databases</option>
        <option value='3' data-toggle="#reserves">Course Reserves</option>
        <option value='4' data-toggle="#guides">Subject & Course Guides</option>
        <option value='5' data-toggle="#cdm">Digital Archives</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The original developer (I think) had the idea of using the index based value (see the value attr) from the select options and then display the tab content for the associated tab pane.

This is the Jquery code he left, but it is not working. And I can't wrap my head around it.

```
/* select tab on select change */
$('#search-nav-select').on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
  $('#search-nav-tabs li a').eq($(this).val()).tab('show');
});
```

Basically, when the select menu option is changed, it should display the corresponding search menu for that resource/collection.

I just need to know what Jquery code I would need to write in order to make that happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the script that you have can not work:

- First, `$(this).val()` return the content of `value` attribute of selected option not value of `data-toggle`
- Secondly: You can't recover an element with an ID `#search-nav-tabs` whereas it's the class of the element `.search-nav-tabs` that you should use

I made a piece of code that should work for your use:

```
$('#search-nav-select').on('change', function() {
  var tabID = $(this).find(":selected").data('toggle');
  $('.search-nav-tabs li a[href="' + tabID + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: That did it! Thank you :)